# Arnautov, Lovasz, Payan bound on domination number

Tags: graph-theory

Recently I've read in a paper (Remarks on the domination number of graphs [Arnautov bound](http://www.math.louisville.edu/~biro/domination.pdf)) that the bound $\gamma(G) \leq \frac{n}{\delta + 1}\sum_{j=1}^{\delta + 1} \frac{1}{j}$ on the domination number of a graph without isolated vertices can be obtained by constructing a dominating set following a specific greedy algorithm. This algorithm was also used in The Probabilistic Method to obtain the Alon bound on the domination number. I tried to have a go at it, and ended up with the following:

After $x$ number of steps, the algorithm gives $\gamma(G) \leq x + n(1-\frac{\delta + 1}{n})^x$. So the best upper bound is obtained by minimizing this function with respect to $x$. Differentiating and equating to zero gives $1+n(1-\frac{\delta + 1}{n})^x\ln(x)=0$. However, I do not know how to go on from here. I'm guessing that  somehow the function $\frac{n}{\delta + 1}\sum_{j=1}^{\delta + 1} \frac{1}{j}$ is the minimum of this upper bound.

If someone can tell me how continue from here or if there is another method to obtain the Arnautov bound it would be greatly appreciated!